# Android rewrite single xml node

Tags: android, android-xml

If I want to change a single value in a node of an xml file on the sdcard (this is not a resource xml file), how would I go about that? In c#, it was easy to load an entire xml file into an XmlDocument, and then manipulate the nodes with code like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"j:\test2.xml");
XmlNode sec1Value = doc.SelectSingleNode("xml/section1/value");
sec1Value.InnerText = "one";
```

unfortunately, Android does not have an XmlDocument class (that I know of).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class like it describe there :http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android/91845/

or use javas classes.